# Сравнение ASCII-символов на ассемблере ARM

Tags: ассемблер, arm

Я создаю простую программу для изменения регистра букв в ASCII со строчного на заглавный. Приведённый ниже код работает как и ожидалось, за исключением сравнения символов (должны быть больше 97 и меньше 122, именно в этом промежутке находятся строчные латинские буквы).

```
.section .data
buff: .skip 64
example: .ascii "abcd"
.section .text

.globl _start
_start:
    MOV R0, #0          @ дескриптор файла (stdin)
    LDR R1, =buff       @ указатель на буфер
    MOV R2, #64         @ размер буфера

    MOV R7, #3          @ вызываем read()
    SWI #0

    MOV R1, R0          @ проходим только по считанным символам
    LDR R0, =buff
    PUSH {R2}           @ сохраняем кол-во символов в стеке
    BL to_upper         @ вызываем to_upper()

    MOV R0, #1          @ дескриптор файла (stdout)
    LDR R1, =buff       @ указатель на буфер
    POP {R2}            @ получаем кол-во символов из стека

    MOV R7, #4          @ вызываем write()
    SWI #0

MOV R7, #1      @ вызываем exit()
SWI #0

@ ОПИСАНИЕ: преобразует все строчные символы в строке
@           в заглавные
@ ИСПОЛЬЗУЕМЫЕ РЕГИСТРЫ: R0, R1, R2, R3
@ АРГУМЕНТЫ: (R0)указатель на строку, (R1)длина строки
@ ВОЗВРАЩАЕМОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ: (R0)
to_upper:
PUSH {LR}
    MOV R2, #0  @ индекс
    upperloop:
        LDR R3, [R0, R2]    @ выгружаем символ
        CMP R3, #97         @ пропускаем символы меньше 'a'
            BGT upperinc        
        CMP R3, #122        @ пропускаем символы больше 'z'
            BLT upperinc

        SUB R3, #32         @ делаем букву заглавной
        STR R3, [R0, R2]    @ возвращаем её обратно
        upperinc:
        CMP R2, R1          @ осторожно: длина строки должна быть как минимум 1
            BEQ upperend    @ (или возможно, получите segmentation fault)
        ADD R2, #1          @ выполняем до конца строки
    B upperloop
    upperend:
POP {PC}
```

Comment: bgt/blt местами поменяйте. надо пропускать символ если он меньше 97 или больше 122, а не наоборот

Comment: Я пробовал менять инструкции местами. Прикол в том, что ничего от этого не изменилось. Если поместить в тот же регистр тот же символ, что и был введён, но через mov, то условие выполняется верно. Не пойму, в чём дело.

Comment: А какого размера у вас регистр ? И какого размера команда загрузки LDR R3, [R0, R2], она точно грузит только 1 байт ? и проверяет ли CMP именно один байт или трактует константу как большего размера ?

Comment: Судя по гуглу для загрузки байта используется LDRB, только я не понял, что она делает со старшими битами регистра, обнуляются ли они. Если нет, то надо очистить регистр R3 перед началом цикла. Сохранять в память надо так же один байт, STRB

Comment: CMP сравнивает только один байт, да. Регистры 32-битные, насколько я помню. А вот сохранение одного байта в регистр действительно помогло! Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых у вас перепутаны условия ухода от обработки символа, символ надо пропускать когда он меньше 97 или когда больше 122.

Во вторых, на архитектуре ARM все операции по умолчанию 32 битные. `LDR R3, [R0, R2]` загружает в R3 сразу 32 бита данных, все 4 буквы (например 0x64636261). А `CMP #R3, #97` сравнивает так же все 32 бита, причем старшие биты берет равные нулю (т.е. 0x00000061). Для загрузки в регистр именно одного байта надо использовать `LDRB`. Так же сохранять байт после преобразования `STRB`